# Python pandas using count

Tags: python, pandas

Getting data from Excel using Python is unavailable.

This is my actual code.

```
import pandas as pd

dataset = pd.read_csv('dane.csv')

a = "-JP"

print(dataset.count(a))
```

SAMPLE
https://gofile.io/d/zjW2EN

I think to use other library or maybe change every data toString(), but I am not sure about my suggestion.

Comment: What do you want to do here? Count string `-JP` in your dataframe?

Comment: I have really huge data let's say PM-JP-xasada-2414 and tousands of that I need to count -JP in every table.

Comment: Please share a sample input with expected output. It's not very clear to me right now.

Comment: V);SG-TH Pushkin (ULCV);MT-IN Astrea (ULCV);BR-US Grossadler (Feedermax);SA-BR Arabella (ULCV);ES-GR Henrietta (New Panamax);MA-MT Dazzler (New Panamax);PA-MT Chelsea (Small feeder);SG-US Literature (Post-Panamax);AE-IN Unicorn (Panamax)
MA-SG-83996625/2585/A1@oxlyo.uk/6145;PA-ES-96031647/2993/B2@tuw.ml/94044;MY-BE-40283751/4079/X1@nxocoezoq.mp/96326;ID-VN-33266337/3165/Y2@uineka.se/69047

Comment: I would like to count how many of "-JP" I can find in the data.

Comment: Please post sample dataframe in the question itself, not in comments.

Comment: OK it is made..

Answer (score 1):

Just use to_string() method to convert your frame to string then count your key.

```
import pandas as pd

dataset = pd.read_csv('dane.csv')

a = "-JP"
print(dataset.to_string().count(a))
```

Like this.

Answer (score 0):

first. invoke count method and get "-JP" using bracket notation.

According to [API Reference](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.count.html):

```
DataFrame.count(axis=0, level=None, numeric_only=False)
// some skipped text..
Parameters
axis: {0 or ‘index’, 1 or ‘columns’}, default 0
If 0 or ‘index’ counts are generated for each column.
If 1 or ‘columns’ counts are generated for each row.

level: int or str, optional
If the axis is a MultiIndex (hierarchical), count along a particular level, collapsing into a DataFrame. A str specifies the level name.
```

you can try this:

```py
print(dataset.count()[a])
```

Comment: wait a minute.. i might my answer is wrong

Comment: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/HP/PycharmProjects/LABDAFT/1daft.py", line 7, in <module>
    print(dataset.count(level=a))
  File "C:\workspace\LABDAFT\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 8457, in count
    return self._count_level(level, axis=axis, numeric_only=numeric_only)
  File "C:\workspace\LABDAFT\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 8492, in _count_level
    raise TypeError(
TypeError: Can only count levels on hierarchical index.

Process finished with exit code 1 `

Comment: i'm sorry. is edited code working?

Comment: I'd like to see sample dataframe. is dash exists in field name? is field signature on first row or first column?

Comment: or might be case sensitive: the distinction of uppercase and lowercase letters.